# Rotation and constraints in swift3 (xcode)

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, rotation, constraints

I am using swift3 in xcode.

I have made an application with 10 sliders which I rotate to vertical using:

```
slider1outlet.transform = CGAffineTransform.init( rotationAngle: CGFloat(-Double.pi / 2))
```

Same goes for slider 2 through 10 this works without a problem,
but I want to add constraints so they go maximum height and are evenly distributed across the width of the screen, and they adapt when I rotate my screen.

This doesn't seem to work, the constraint seems to turn with the slider and I don't want that.

I have made screenshots (with only 3 sliders just for demo purposes)
the first slider has a red background to show what I mean, here is the screenshot of the application without rotating the sliders:

[image: No rotation]

With the rotating sliders (only 1st slider has red background)

[image: With rotation]

Answer (score 0):

I had **exactly** the same problem, and it took me forever to figure out. I finally ended up writing my own class exactly for this: [`VerticalSlider`](https://gist.github.com/Coder-256/01c6f8df7043bf7a2a7e100015a533c0).

Simply make new `UISlider`s in your storyboard and set their classes to `VerticalSlider`.

It took me countless hours of trial and error in one of my projects to make that, so I'm glad I can finally help somebody else :D